# Why am I getting error 1064 when creating a table?

Tags: mysql

Here is my DDL statement:

```
create table if not exists 'fmrecruit'.'resource_type'(
  'ID' bigint not null auto_increment,
  'type' bigint null,
  'first_name' varchar(30) not null,
  'middle_name' varchar(30) null,
  'last_name' varchar(30) null,
  'org_name' varchar(45) null,
  'notes' varchar(256) null,
  'primary_skills' varchar(256) not null,
  'seconadary_skills' varchar(256) null,
  'created_by' varchar(25) not null,
  'created_date' timestamp not null,
  'updated_by' varchar(25) null,
  'updated_date' timestamp null,
  primary key('ID'),
  index resource_type_fk_idx('type' asc),
  constraint resource_type_fk foreign key('type') refrences fmrecruit.resource_type('ID')
  on delete no action
  on update no action)
  engine=innodb;
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating a table, you should not use single quotes (') to enclose table or column names, but instead use backticks (`` ` ``) to enclose table and column names, when required.

See [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html) in the MySQL documentation.

If [`ANSI_QUOTES` mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks (`"`).